# How does Samsung S-View Flip Cover work?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, smart-cover

How does the S-View Flip Cover work? I know some apps that use the proximity sensor to check this and turn on and turn off the screen.

S-View Flip Cover does not require any softwares, so how does it communicate with the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple. There are hidden magnets in the front part of the flip cover. These magnets tell the device that S-View Flip Cover is attached.

The glass window that is on the cover is conductive, through which you can operate only that much part of the screen leaving the rest of the screen non operable to avoid accidental touch.

The idea behind is just like the Apple smart cover. What makes the S-View Flip Cover different is the conductive window functionality to accept or reject calls etc.

Comment: okay.So does this affect the compass adversely like some flipcovers with magentic flaps do? I want to get a new Fcover,what i have is one with magnet,the compass seems to go crazy when opening and closing the cover.

Comment: Yes it unfortunately does due to the magnetic elements.

Answer (score 4):

I think that there is another element to this - but I have not determined what it is - There is one magnet in the front of the flip cover lets the device know that the cover is open or shut - but it will not work unless the case back is attached to the phone - and there are some contacts in the back cover of the flip case that connect to the phone - I cannot find any magnets in the case back, so I presume that the connections in the case back let the phone know that there is a flip cover installed.

I am working on figuring the rest of this out because I would like to use a different case (not the flip) and have a magnet in my holster to unlock the phone when I take it out of the holster.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic flip covers use hall effect sensor to switch screen on n off, for example you can cover ur screen with a magnet n the screen goes blank, so does the hall effect sensor

Comment: This does not provide any new information from the top-voted [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/64723/11190).